# Google PubSub Emulator cannot list Project Subscriptions

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-publisher-tag, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I am using the Google PubSub emulator (locally with Docker) and trying to list the available subscriptions on my project. I am not using any authentication (it's just local development), using Docker and simple Java app, but I am running into this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: The request is missing a valid API key.
```

This is my docker-compose code for the emulator:

```
gcloud:
    image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli
    container_name: my-gcloud
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    entrypoint: gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project emulator-project --host-port 0.0.0.0:8085 --verbosity=debug
```

This is how I create the topic (rest API, including a successful response):

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/emulator-project/topics/test-topic
// response is:                                                                               
{
  "name": "projects/emulator-project/topics/test-topic"
}
```

I can retrieve the topic via REST and it's fine (so I assume the topic is succesfullly created):

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/emulator-project/topics                                                                                                                             
    
{
  "topics": [{
    "name": "projects/emulator-project/topics/test-topic"
  }]
}
```

I add subscriptions also with the REST API:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/emulator-project/subscriptions' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "name": "projects/emulator-project/subscriptions/test-subscription",
    "topic": "projects/emulator-project/topics/test-topic"
  }'
```

However, using my Java code for retrieving the subscriptions inside the project, if any, I bump into the error(s) above:

```
 public class PubSubPublisherExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient
                .create(SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                        .build())) {

            for (Subscription subscription : subscriptionAdminClient.listSubscriptions("emulator-project")
                    .iterateAll()) {
                System.out.println("Subscription: " + subscription.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried not specifying the settings, or using the `NoCredentials` provider and if I do, then it somehow defaults to my production project account (although I have no environment variable or configuration to point to it, as I am testing in a simple Java app):

```
`Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Caller does not have required permission to use project SOME_PROD_PROJECT`.
```

Moreover there are no extra logs in the emulator container either.

Is there anyway I can simply use the local emulator project for any topic/subscription related interaction or is this an emulator limitation?

Comment: Corrections done to the initial question, should be clear and correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some (more) days of searching, I have identified two main problems with my previous code. Posting my minimal solution here, as this might help other people starting with Google PubSub (and the emulator).

1. The `SubscriptionAdminClient` needed to be created differently (at least to work with the emulator):

   ```
   String hostport = "localhost:8085";
   ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(hostport).usePlaintext().build();

   TransportChannelProvider channelProvider = FixedTransportChannelProvider.create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel));
   CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = NoCredentialsProvider.create();

   SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient
                = SubscriptionAdminClient.create(SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider)
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build()
        );
   ```

2. The listing of subscriptions did not work with a simple String as project name (at least for me). Using a `ProjectName` instance fixed this too:

   ```
   ProjectName projectName = ProjectName.of("emulator-project");
   for (Subscription subscription : subscriptionAdminClient.listSubscriptions(projectName).iterateAll()) {
       System.out.println("Existing subscriptions: " + subscription.getName());
   }
   ```

With the code above, I no longer get API key (or credentials) related warnings/errors. This is enough to get my sample going.

(Again I needed to use this just for a small example, not for something production ready)

PS Using a similar way of creating the `TopicAdminClient`, I was able to created topics via code (not just through the REST API) and with this `SubscriptionAdminClient` I was able to create subscriptions in code too. In the end, I did not require the REST API, but it was useful for simple logging/debugging at first.

Comment: See the code sample in the documentation [Accessing environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#pubsub-emulator-java)

Comment: @DazWilkin yes yes, that was exactly the part of docs that got it me in the right direction